# How many types of Dasa are there in total?

Tags: astrology, dasha, vimshottari-dasha, brihat-parashara-hora-shastra

Although Vimosttari is popular and more applicable dasa among all, there are still may other type of dasa.

Some of them are Astottari,  Shodsottari,  Dwadasottari,  Panchottari,  Satabdika,     Chaturshiti-sama,  Dwisaptati-sama,  Shastibayani,  Shatvinsa-sama,     Kalachakra,  Chakra,  Chara,  Sthira,  Kendra,  Brahmagraha,     Mandook,  Yogardha,  Shoola,  Drig,  Trikona,  Rasi,  Panchaswara,     Yogini,  Naisargik, Pinda,   Sandhya,  Ashtavarga,  Pachaka,  Tara.

The list has been taken from the Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra.

Do any scripture contains the total list of types of dasa? How many types of dasa are there in total and what are their names?

Comment: There are a total of *47* dashas according to my Guruji. If you count the number of Dashas in JHora, the number is just around the same. The only thing is, I lack textual evidence.