# What is BrahmaGraha?

Tags: brahman, hanuman, evil

In [MarutiKavacham](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_hanumaana/mArutikavacham.html) one might come across the following.

> ...काकिनीकामिनीग्रहबन्धनाय ।
> **ब्रह्मग्रहबन्धनाय । ब्रह्मराक्षसग्रहबन्धनाय** । चोरग्रहबन्धनाय ।
> मारीग्रहबन्धनाय । एहि एहि....

> ...Kākinīkāminīgrahabandhanāya **brahmagrahabandhanāya  brahmarākṣasagrahabandhanāya** cōragrahabandhanāya mārīgrahabandhanāya...

There are two words '**BrahmaGraha**bandhanāya' and '**BrahmaRākṣasaGraha**bandhanāya'.

**What is 'BrahmaGraha'? It's quite clear that 'BrahmaGraha' is different than BrahmaRākṣasaGraha.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly quoting from [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/43544/17833) question on HSE itself, which in short, (kind of) gives the answer to your question:

> Although [Vimsottari](http://www.saravali.de/articles/dasa_vimsottari.html) is popular and more applicable daśā (दशा ) among all,
> there are still may other type of dasa.
>
> Some of them are Astottari, Shodsottari, Dwadasottari, Panchottari,
> Satabdika, Chaturshiti-sama, Dwisaptati-sama, Shastibayani,
> Shatvinsa-sama, Kalachakra, Chakra, Chara, Sthira, Kendra,
> **Brahmagraha**, Mandook, Yogardha, Shoola, Drig, Trikona, Rasi,
> Panchaswara, Yogini, Naisargik, Pinda, Sandhya, Ashtavarga, Pachaka,
> Tara.
>
> *[The above list has been taken from the [Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](https://archive.org/details/BPHSEnglish/BPHS%20-%201%20RSanthanam).]*

---

Thus,

***Brahmagraha (ब्रह्मग्रह )* is an astrology -*Jyotiṣa Śāstra (ज्योतिष शास्त्र )* related term, which relates to the graha daśā (ग्रह दशा), which is formed as a result of certain planetary combinations in the Janmakuṇḍalī of the jātaka (whose Kuṇḍalī is being analysed).**

---

Further,

***Brahma Graha*** is explained in precise details in this  excerpt from [Chapter 46. Dashas of Grahas](https://instapdf.in/preview/?pdfid=5349&_gl=1*1xxjq68*_ga*ck1KM24xV2ZaMlFvTkZVN3VQdzIzaUNrZDVOcnpVb09QY1JEVmNaQzJrZF9HQjNYWm1iRFBIazlSck9qZ09qQQ..) of the Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra:

> 170-173.  Maitreya  said.  O  great  Sage!  Now  please  enlighten  me
> how  the *Brahm  Graha*  is  picked  out  in  a  chart.  Maharishi
> Parashar  said.  **From amongst  the  Lords  of  Ari,  Randhr  and
> Vyaya  the  Grah,  who  may  possess the  greatest  strength  and  is
> placed  in  Lagn,  or  in  Yuvati  with  strength,  the one,  placed
> in  an  odd  Rāśi  within  sixth  Bhava  from  the  Bhava  concerned,
> is called  the  Brahm  Grah.**  The  Lord  of  Randhr  in  Randhr  is
> also  accepted,  as **Brahm  Grah**.  If  Śani,  or  Rahu/Ketu  obtain
> Brahmatva  (qualifications  of Brahm  Grah),  they  become  Brahm
> Grah.  If  a  number  of  Grahas  obtain Brahmatva,  the  one  with
> the  largest  number  of  degrees  would  become **Brahm  Grah**.  If
> there  is  parity  in  the  degrees  of  such  Grahas,  the  most
> powerful  amongst  them  would become  **Brahm  Grah.**

---

Furthermore, [this](https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/ProfAnthonyWriter/brahma-rudra-maheshwra), article based on Gemini Astrology discuss the concept in more detail, albeit in a different way or methodology per say, to calculate and find various kinds of Brahma Graha combinations.

---

Another [article](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/a-history-of-indian-philosophy-volume-2/d/doc209906.html#note-e-27207), from a contemporary ayurveda history book **based on *Atharva Veda***, delineates ***Brahmagraha* as a class of evil demons or spirits, which caused some ailments or diseases**. Basically, representing the disease causing agents in a personified form of evil spirits or demons.

The Book 2, [Verse 9](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6mg4DQAAQBAJ&pg=PT5&dq=%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%20%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%20%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij8JfNrbXvAhUGYysKHbqyA1UQ6AEwAHoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%20%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%20%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6&f=false) of the *Atharva Veda* also make some reference to this as a disease and alludes to some charms and rituals to mitigate it and relieve the afflicted from its malefic effects.
The english translation by [Griffith](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av02009.htm) for the same verse, however, doesn't mention any *Brahma graha* specifically.

---

**tl;dr**

- *Brahma Graha* is a planet calculated as per relevant methods of astrology, to understand the malefic effect of the planetary *daśās* vis-a vis the so called - *Sthira daśās ( स्थिर दशा )* and the *Māraka daśās ( मारक दशा )* in a horoscope.
- Or, *Brahma Graha* is an evil spirit or demon which causes ailments and diseases.